асоциация vscode
Пишу код на пайтон в vscode
def index(request):
    name = tuple(zodiac_dict.keys())
    li_elements = ''
    for sing in name:
        redirect_path = reverse("nnnnnnn", args=(sing,))
        li_elements += f'<li> <a href="{redirect_path}"> {sing.title()} </a> </li>'

И мне нужно что бы вот эта "строка" (как тип в пайтон)
<li> <a href="{redirect_path}"> {sing.title()} </a> </li>

ассоциировалась vscode как html. Возможно ли провернуть подобное? Так же например и с запросами sql?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64275816/highlight-html-in-python-string

муть какая-то. Спасибо но я как нить без этого тогда...
